# useEffect hook is not reading the changes to 'keys' from 'localstorage' after first mount

Tags: react-hooks, local-storage, token, addeventlistener, refresh-token

In below code I am using useEffect hook to check if local storage has token or not. If yes then it sets user "true" but here after successful sign-in and local storage stores a token, useEffect is not setting user to "true" unless you refresh the page and once you refresh the page it sets user to "true". check and find the issue.
Same is with sign-out, sign-out component just clears the whole local storage but useEffect is not detecting changes until page is refreshed or "window.location.reload()" is called.

```
App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import TopNavbar from "./components/LandingPage/navbar";
import MainNavbar from "./components/LandingPage/mainNavbar";
import Footer from "./components/LandingPage/footer";
import Home from "./components/LandingPage/home";
import Features from "./components/LandingPage/features";
import Services from "./components/LandingPage/services";
import MainApp from "./MainApp";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Function to check the token and set the user state
    const checkToken = () => {
      if (token) {
        setUser(true);
      } else {
        setUser(false);
      }
    };

    // Check the token initially on mount
    checkToken();

    // Add event listener to handle changes in local storage
    const handleStorageChange = () => {
      setToken(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    };

    window.addEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);

    // Clean up the event listener on unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <>
      {user ? (
        <>
          <MainNavbar />
          <MainApp />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <TopNavbar />
          <Home />
          <Features />
          <Services />
        </>
      )}

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
Sign-In Component

import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import "./styles.css";

export default function SignInModal(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleClose = () => {
    setError("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    props.onHide();
  };

  const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const signInData = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    try {
      const url = "http://localhost:4501/user/signin";
      const response = await axios.post(url, signInData);
      const { token, firstName } = response.data.data;
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      localStorage.setItem("firstName", firstName);
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event("tokenUpdated"));
      handleClose();
      //window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.response &&
        error.response.status >= 400 &&
        error.response.status <= 500
      ) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        console.error("Error occurred during sign in:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      onHide={handleClose}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="modal-signin"
      centered
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSignIn}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="modal-signin">Sign In</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <FloatingLabel
            controlId="floatingInput"
            label="Email address"
            className="mb-3"
          >
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FloatingLabel>
          <FloatingLabel
            controlId="floatingPassword"
            label="Password"
            className="mb-3"
          >
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FloatingLabel>
          {error && <div className="error_msg">{error}</div>}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

```
Sign-Out Component

import React from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import "./styles.css";

export default function SignOutModal(props) {
  const userName = localStorage.getItem("firstName");

  const handleClose = () => {
    props.onHide();
  };

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("tokenUpdated"));
    handleClose();
    //window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      onHide={handleClose}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="modal-signout"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="modal-signout">Sign Out</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <h5>{userName}! Do you really want to Sign Out?</h5>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleSignOut}>
          Sign Out
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

The useEffect hook should detect the changes to the "token" value using "window.addEventListener" and set the "user" value accordingly but it is not working. Every time page reload is required in this condition while useEffect is not working.